# Calculating Elapsed Days From Pandas Dataframe Strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `Pandas` `dataframe` that stores travel dates of people. I'd like to add a column that shows the length of the stay. To do this the `string` needs to be parsed, converted to a `datetime` and subtracted. `Pandas` seems to be treating the `datetime` conversion as a whole series and not individual `strings`  as a I get `TypeError: must be string, not Series`. I like to do this with a non-looping option as the actual dataset is quite large, but need a bit of help.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Bob', '12 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015'], ['Jessica', '27 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015']], columns=['Names', 'Day of Visit'])
df['Length of Stay'] = (datetime.strptime(df['Day of Visit'][:11], '%d %b %Y') - datetime.strptime(df['Day of Visit'][-11:], '%d %b %Y')).days + 1
print df
```

Desired Output:

```
    Names               Day of Visit  Length of Stay
0      Bob  12 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015              20
1  Jessica  27 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015               5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Series.str.extract` to split the `Day of Visit` column into two separate columns.
Then use `pd.to_datetime` to parse the columns as dates.
Computing the `Length of Stay` can then be done by subtracting the date columns and adding 1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Bob', '12 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015'], ['Jessica', '27 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015']], columns=['Names', 'Day of Visit'])
tmp = df['Day of Visit'].str.extract(r'([^-]+)-(.*)', expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['Length of Stay'] = (tmp[1] - tmp[0]).dt.days + 1
print(df)
```

yields

```
     Names               Day of Visit  Length of Stay
0      Bob  12 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015              20
1  Jessica  27 Mar 2015 - 31 Mar 2015               5
```

---

The [regex pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) `([^-]+)-(.*)` means

```
(              # start group #1
  [            # begin character class
    ^-         # any character except a literal minus sign `-`
  ]            # end character class 
   +           # match 1-or-more characters from the character class
)              # end group #1
-              # match a literal minus sign 
(              # start group #2
  .*           # match 0-or-more of any character
)              # end group #2
```

`.str.extract` returns a DataFrame with the matching text from groups #1 and #2 in columns.

Comment: Thanks. I need to look into regular expression because that looks like gibberish to me. If I don't want to helper column, `start` and `end`, is the best thing to do just drop right after being used?

Comment: I've modified the code to place the helper columns in `tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
def length_of_stay(x):
    start, end = [datetime.strptime(d, '%d %b %Y') for d in x.split(' - ')]
    return end - start

df['Length of Stay'] = df['Day of Visit'].apply(length_of_stay)
print df
```